# Embed Ruby Code Inside a Javascript Call

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I've read other threads about this topic but they do not seem to work for me, so my apologies in advance if I'm just thick-headed on this topic.

I have a view in Rails thats shows a large image 700x200 (we call it a slide).  Under this large image I have several thumbnail images showing.  When I click on a thumbnail, I want the large image of that thumbnail to appear in the large image above the thumbnails.

I'm using Rails 3.2 and PaperClip for the images.

My view code:

```
<div id="slider">
  <%= image_tag @first_image.image.url(:full) %>
</div>
<% @slides.each do |s| %>
  <div id="slider_tn">
    <ul>
      <li><%= s.id %> <%= image_tag s.image.url(:thumb), {:onclick =>"$('#slider').html("+image_tag.url(:full)+")"} %></li>
      <li>Title: <%= s.title %></li>
      <li>URL:  <%= s.url %></li>
      <li><%= link_to("Edit", action: "edit", id: s.id) %></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Inside the :onclick section is where I'm having trouble. I get a "Wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2). I try to add in ruby tags:

```
<%= s.id %> <%= image_tag s.image.url(:thumb), {:onclick =>"$('#slider').html("+<%= image_tag.url(:full) %>+")"} %>
```

...but this gets me the error: Unexpected '<', which I understand.
I've tried to assign the image_tag.url(:full) to a javascript var, as seen in other posts, and use that, but that doesn't work for me either.

Any ideas on how to get this to work.

Much appreciated for any help/tips.

Answer (score 0):

You can't open a tag inside a tag. What you want is to escape ruby code from a String that you're already defining inside a tag. Use #{}.

```
<%= image_tag s.image.url(:thumb), {:onclick =>"$('#slider').html(#{image_tag.url(:full)})"} %>
```

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#Interpolation

Comment: Hallucynogenyc: Thanks.  I've tried:  {:onclick =>"$('#slider').html(#{image_tag.url(:full)})"}  and {:onclick =>"$('#slider').html("+#{image_tag.url(:full)})+"}, but neither work.  Can you be a bit more specific?  Thanks,

Comment: I haven't tested my code, but it should work. Your problem was using a tag inside a tag, that's why you were getting Unexpected '<'. Use interpolation if you need to embed ruby code inside a string.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should use `image_tag s.image.url(:full)` instead of `image_tag.url(:full)`:

```
<%= image_tag s.image.url(:thumb), {:onclick => "$('#slider').html(#{image_tag s.image.url(:full)})"} %>
```